# Trouble finding on-board serial port via UART: "-bash: echo: write error: Input/output error"

Tags: embedded, arm, serial-port, uart

I have an old tv box that I wiped recently with Linux. I would like to connect a device to its onboard UART pins, to which I've soldered wires that connect to a UART adapter on my PC. I opened up a PuTTY serial monitor that reads incoming data while simultaneously trying to send data from the tv box. But whenever I try to interact with any of the `ttyS*` ports, I just get `-bash: echo: write error: Input/output error`. I've tried using `echo`, `screen` and `minicom`, but all of them seem to spit out the same error. While messing around with `setserial`, I get these kinds of error messages:

```
root@arm-64:~# setserial /dev/ttyS1 uart 16550
Cannot set serial info: Invalid argument
```

I'm totally unsure what to do, it seems almost as if it's none of these four ports, but I don't see another option for UART. I'm looking to at least verify the port name that my device is connected to so I can use it down the line.

TV Box model:
Tx mini 3 s905w processor

Answer (score 0):

> wiped with Linux [..] it seems almost as if it's none of these four ports

That's likely what it is: the standard four ttyS devices are created for the standard IBM PC UARTs, which probably don't exist on your TV box, as it's not based on IBM PC chipsets.

Options:

- Get information from the TV box's PCB (or the communicate that told you how to wipe it and install Linux) about the hardware and which driver you need
- Look at the old firmware (if you have a backup) to see if it has a driver for it.

By the way, it helps **immensely** to mention the precise brand and model of the TV box in the question, because then I could google for this information for you.

Comment: my mistake, added it in the OP